# How to crawl local HTML file with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I tried to crawl a local HTML file stored in my desktop with the code below, but I encounter the following errors before crawling procedure, such as "No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'".

- Is it possible to crawl local HTML files in a local computer(Mac)?
- If possible, how should I
  set parameters like "allowed_domains" and "start_urls"?

[Scrapy command]

```
$ scrapy crawl test -o test01.csv
```

[Scrapy spider]

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['file:///Users/Name/Desktop/test/test.html']
```

[Errors]

```
2018-11-16 01:57:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-16 01:57:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-16 01:57:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-11-16 01:57:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET file:///robots.txt> (failed 1 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'
2018-11-16 01:57:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET file:///robots.txt> (failed 2 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'
```

Comment: Hi @Baka, I'm glad that the issue is now resolved. FYI that I've just rolled back your last edit to the question. Reason: Fixing your question and making it the "correct" version would confuse future readers, especially those who has the similar issue and seeks help.

Comment: @starrify, I agree with your opinion, you are right. Thank you for making my question valuable :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with it locally, I never specify the `allowed_domains`.
Try to take that line of code out and see if it works.

In your error its testing the 'empty' domain that you have given it.

Comment: Thanks, @japes. I modified according to your advice, but I still get the same errors as before. Please see the updated code in the question above. I totally erased "allowed_domains" row.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you for your help, @japes! I modified according to your advice, then the code generated a csv file as I expected :-D

Comment: Glad it worked out! :) Could you please mark it as answered if possible?

Comment: Oooops, my mistake. I'm still new in the SO community. Thanks to take your time to notice me :-) I put the checkmark on your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error of "No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'" you can go to settings.py file and comment the line:

```
#ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```