# How to use Scrapy on local files without getting the robot.txt errors?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get Scrapy to scrape a local file, not a URL website using HTTPS.  I got some errors related to the robots.txt file:

```
2020-07-13 23:58:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET file:///robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'
2020-07-13 23:58:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET file:///robots.txt>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/file.py", line 15, in download_request
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as fo:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/robots.txt'
```

I found a post of a similar problem on StackOverFlow:

[How to crawl local HTML file with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325150/how-to-crawl-local-html-file-with-scrapy)

But the solution in that post says that the problem is because of the **allowed_domains** variable.  I don't define this variable at all in my spider:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test_schedule"

    season_flag = False
    season_val = ""

    """
    I need to override the __init__() method of scrapy.Spider
    because I need to define some attributes/variables from run-time arguments
    """
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(TestSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.season_flag = False
        self.debug_flag = False
        self.season_val = ""

        # Get some run-time arguments
        if hasattr(self, "season"):
            self.season_val = str(self.season)
            self.season_flag = True


    """
    Note: I never define an allowed_domains list
    anywhere in start_requests()
    """
    def start_requests(self):
        schedule_filename = "home/foo.html"

        # I check to see that the file 'foo.html' exists.
        # The file exists but I still get a "robot.txt not found" error
        if not os.path.exists(schedule_filename):
            stmt = "test file doesn't exist"
            self.log(stmt)
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            stmt = " *** test file exists ***"
            self.log(stmt)

        url_list = [
            "file:///home/foo.html"
        ]

        for url in url_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,\
              callback=self.parse_schedule_page)

    """
    Method that will parse the response from
    the scrapy.Request call.
    """
    def parse_schedule_page(self, response):

        game_elements_list = response.xpath("//table[@id = 'games']/tbody/tr")
        num_game_elements = len(game_elements_list)

        # etc., etc., etc. but the program flow doesn't even get here
```

Do I have to set some configuration setting or use a runtime argument to let Scrapy know that I'm pointing Scrapy to a local file?  The link I referenced doesn't mention anything about this.

Scrapy's error message says that it cannot find robot.txt.  Since I am using "file:///" instead of "https", shouldn't Scrapy not even look for a robots.txt file?

Comment: This seems to be caused by the middleware, have you tried running it with `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in your settings? If I'm not mistaken this will disable `RobotsTxtMiddleware`.

Comment: @renatodvc, your solution solved the problem!  Thanks.

Could you answer the question so this post can help others who have the same problem as me in the future?

Comment: Hi @SQA777, since you mentioned leaving it as an answer and it solved the issue, I will ask you to please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Thanks.

Comment: @renatodvc, checkmarked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `RobotsTxtMiddleware` trying to download a `robots.txt`, it can be solved by disabling the middleware. You can set you `settings.py` to

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

This will cause the middleware to be disabled, as it raises a `NotConfigured` exception. ([source](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/robotstxt.html#RobotsTxtMiddleware))

Another way to disable this middleware (and every other builtin middleware) is to set it to `None` in `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` (inside `settings.py`) as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware):

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt': None,
}
```